# database one-time setup in django

Tags: python, django

I have a django app that requires a few rows in the database before even starting the app or lettings users sign up, etc.

These include: groups, foriegn key fields, and even a couple of administrative users.

Currently, I have a script `start.py` that I execute which does things like create groups, users, assign admin users to groups, and so on.

It seems as though there might be a better more django-ish way to do this. Perhaps putting this in `settings.py`? Some other way entirely?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use fixtures for this.
For details please visit 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/

Answer (score 1):

The Django way to do it is to use [Data Migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#data-migrations). It's definitely recommended over fixtures (which I think are used mainly for testing data)

Basically you will make schema migrations in which you will define Models, Fields, etc. After creating all the necessary Models to hold your data you will create an additional migration in which you'll run code akin to `Model.objects.create(field1='value1')`.

I found [this guide](https://realpython.com/blog/python/data-migrations/) to be great help in understanding. Here's the example included in it:

```
# encoding: utf8
from django.db import models, migrations
from datetime import date

def load_data(apps, schema_editor):
    PriceHistory = apps.get_model("historical_data", "PriceHistory")

    PriceHistory(date=date(2013,11,29),
         price=1234.00,
         volume=354564,
         total_btc=12054375,
         ).save()
    PriceHistory(date=date(2012,11,29),
         price=12.15,
         volume=187947,
         total_btc=10504650,
         ).save()


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('historical_data', '0002_auto_20140710_0810'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(load_data)
    ]
```

Notice that the only difference from schema migrations is the `migrations.RunPython` call to a custom function that creates whatever data you want.

This used to be a bit of a pain with South, but since Migrations were including in vanilla Django on version 1.7 (by the same developer as South) it's been really easy, thanks to the straightforward code now generated in said migrations.